# Porting SystemV init script to systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I am in the process of porting over a custom Linux init system from SystemV to systemd.  This init system runs a script that interrupts the normal boot process to handle some firmware versioning before bind mounting the selected version and continuing on with the boot process.

With my SystemV setup, I had /sbin/init call /etc/inittab (no /etc/rc present at this time).  Then, inittab would launch the custom boot script with the following line:

```
si:S:sysinit:/opt/pkg/var/oem/etc/init.d/boot
```

Since my script needs to be run very early in the init process, I thought I would add it to the sysinit.target.wants directory.

/lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/custom_init.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom System Initialization Routine
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/init.d/boot
Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/boot
```

However, when I boot the system, I get the following errors:

```
basic.target: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
basic.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
basic.target: Found dependency on custom_init.service/start
basic.target: Found dependency on basic.target/start
basic.target: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job custom_init.service.service/start
custom_init.service.service: Job custom_init.service.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping Custom System Initialization Routine
```

I think the .service file should be run immediately after sbin/init (lib/systemd/systemd) is executed.  Is sysinit.target.wants the correct location for this action?

Any thoughts on how I can rewrite this .service file to perform the same role as my old inittab without this ordering issue?  I would like to make as few changes as possible to the boot script itself.

Comment: You have a condition that it should be executed before `sysinit.target` but you placed it in `sysinit.target.wants`. You should place it in `default.target.wants` if you prefer to keep the condition `before sysinit.target`. The best way is to place it in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and add an `[Install]` section with an entry `WantedBy=default.target` or if you prefer `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.

Comment: You can keep it in `sysinit-target.wants` but you have to modify the condition to run it. Since you never mentioned what needs to be running and what shouldn't be running when you script runs, it's hard to advice what `Before=` or `After=` condition to use.

Comment: To get a clear picture of what systemd has, you can run `systemctl list-dependencies`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is missing `DefaultDependencies=no` - which also means that you *do* need to specify the subset that you *do* need manually

Comment: Also, if you're doing a bind-mount, you probably want `.mount` unit - which *does* affect the set of dependencies ... possibly even systemd will let it load lazily?

Comment: @o11c, can you clarify what you mean by subset?

Comment: @joshua.kurland See the various `systemd.{service,mount,...}` man pages and look at `AUTOMATIC DEPENDENCIES`, then look at the (recursive) dependencies of those (with `systemctl list-dependencies`). Then, figure out which if them you need in order to run your unit.